# How to disable button when returned books is equal with original books volume?

Tags: php

I am making a book management system.I have a return button ,with that button user can return books.

Here is my release-books.php:

```
<?php

$sql_select = "SELECT * FROM carti ORDER BY titlu";

$rezultat = mysqli_query($conn, $sql_select);

if (mysqli_num_rows($rezultat) > 0) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rezultat)) {
        $disabled = $row['stoc'] > 0 ? "" : "disabled"; ?>
<tr><td><input type="submit" name="id" value="<?php echo $row['idCarte']; ?>" <?php echo $disabled; ?> formaction="imprumutare.php"></input></td>
<td><input type="submit" name="returnare" value="<?php echo $row['idCarte']; ?>"  formaction="returnare_carte.php"></input>

</td>
<td><input type="text" name="nume" value="<?php echo $row['titlu']; ?>" ></input></td>

<td><input type="text" name="" value="<?php echo $row['autor']; ?>"></input></td>
<td><input type="text" name="" value="<?php echo $row['editura']; ?>"></input></td>
<td><input type="text" name="" value="<?php echo $row['categorie']; ?>"></input></td>
<td><input type="text" name="" value="<?php echo $row['data_adaugarii']; ?>"></input></td>
<td><input type="text" name="" value="<?php echo $row['stoc']; ?>"></input></td>

</tr>

<?php
    }
}
?>
```

And here is my borrowing.php
include('conexiune.php');

```
//sfarsit if
//Imprumutare
if (isset($_POST['id'])) {
    $identificator = $_POST['id'];
    $carte_nume = $_POST['nume'];

    $current_date = date('y:m:d');
    $current_date_plus_14days = date('y:m:d', strtotime("+14 days"));

    $nume_carte = $_POST['nume'];

    $insert_in_imprumuturi = "INSERT INTO imprumuturi(idc,nume_carte,data,termen_returnare,carti_imprumutate) VALUES('$identificator','$carte_nume','$current_date','$current_date_plus_14days','1')";

    mysqli_query($conn, $insert_in_imprumuturi) or die(mysqli_error($conn));

    $sql_rezervare = "UPDATE carti SET stoc=stoc-1 WHERE iDCarte='$identificator' ";
    if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql_rezervare)) {
        header('Refresh:0,url=emitere_carti.php');
    } else {
        die(mysqli_error($conn));
    }
}
```

But I do not know how to disable the return button when the returned books volume is equal or greater that the originial volume
Can somone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check If your books volume is equal or greater than original volume, if it is.  Use PHP echo  to disable the Return Button.

```
  <button type="submit" name="return"
      <?php 
           if($returned_books_volume >= $original_books_volume){ 
               echo 'disabled';
           } 
       ?> 
   >Return</button>
```